# How can i parse specific string from text file reading all lines?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In each line i want to parse the string after the tag

I know it's html but i copied this part of the html to text file.
For example the first two lines in the text file are like this:

```
<li>602 — <a href="/w/index.php?title=Text602&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Text602 (page does not exist)">Text602</a> document</li>
<li>ABW — <a href="/wiki/AbiWord" title="AbiWord">AbiWord</a> Document</li>
```

I want to parse the 602 from the first line and the ABW from the second line.
What i tried to do is:

```
private void ParseFilesTypes()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\New folder (44)\New Text Document.txt");
            foreach (string str in lines)
            {
                int r = str.IndexOf("<li>");
                if (r >= 0)
                {
                    int i = str.IndexOf(" -", r + 1);
                    if (i >= 0)
                    {

                        int c = str.IndexOf(" -", i + 1);
                        if (c >= 0)
                        {
                            i++;
                            MessageBox.Show(str.Substring(i, c - i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But c is all the time -1

Comment: If you open the file using notepad, do you get unrecognized character instead of "—" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a case when regex would be useful (unless there will be no `li` attributes):

```
var regex = new Regex("^<li>(.+) —");
foreach (string str in lines)
{
     var m = regex.Match(str);
     if (m.Success)
        MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: This is almost working fine but in some results i'm getting for example AFP — Advanced Function Presentation and it should be only AFP and in some other results i'm getting for exmaple: <a href="/wiki/DOC_(computing)" class="mw-redirect" title="DOC (computing)">DOC</a> and this should not be a result at all. Or: <a href="/wiki/HTML" title="HTML">HTML</a>  Most of the results are fine but some i'm getting this. I added the results to a List<string> instead the messageBox.Show

Comment: Fixed it by adding this checking: if (!result.Contains("<li>") && !result.Contains("<a href")) now it's working perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your problem is that you're reading the file with the **incorrect encoding**. You have a special character in your file `—` and not `-`. So you need to correct this character in your code and read the file in the correct encoding. If you debug your string read with wrong encoding, you'll see a black diamond instead of `—`.

Also, you need to remove the space before `—` or replace `i + 1` with `i`;

```
private static void ParseFilesTypes()
{
    string sampleFilePath = @"log.txt";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"log.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));
    foreach (string str in lines)
    {
        int r = str.IndexOf("<li>");
        if (r >= 0)
        {
            int i = str.IndexOf(" —", r + 1);
            if (i >= 0)
            {

                int c = str.IndexOf(" —", i);
                if (c >= 0)
                {
                    i++;
                    int startIndex = r + "<li>".Length;
                    int length = i - startIndex - 1;
                    string result = str.Substring(r + "<li>".Length, length);
                    MessageBox.Show(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and getting exception on the MessageBox.Show line:  Length cannot be less than zero 'i' value is 8 and 'c' is 7 that;s in the first time it's getting i'm using a break point. Also instead messageBow.Show i'm using List<string> to add the results. But i'm getting this exception.

Comment: I dont see black diamond when using notepad since the text file i created it my self and when saved it i saved it as utf-8 and still when editing now the file in notepad i see the symbol — fine.

Comment: @מנימנחם Check the edited answer above on how to get the result from the string.